# Spring Autowired annotion of service is null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I have RestController class that calls Presenter to get some data.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="notes/api")
public class NotesRestController {

    private GetAllNotesPresenter getAllNotesPresenter;

    @RequestMapping(value="/all")
    public List<Note> getAll() {
        getAllNotesPresenter = new GetAllNotesPresenterImpl();
        return getAllNotesPresenter.getAll();
    }
}
```

Inside Presenter class I call DataSource (not Spring Repository, just DAO class).

```
public class GetAllNotesPresenterImpl implements GetAllNotesPresenter {

    private NotesDataSource dataSource;
    private NotesRepository repository;

    public GetAllNotesPresenterImpl() {
        dataSource = new DatabaseDataSource();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Note> getAll() {
        return dataSource.getAll();
    }
}
```

Inside DataSource class I want to do @Autowire of Spring service, but I get **null pointer exception.** Service is always null.

```
@Component
public class DatabaseDataSource implements NotesDataSource {

    @Autowired
    private NotesService notesService;

    public DatabaseDataSource() {
    }

    @Override
    public List<Note> getAll() {
        return notesService.getAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: The code does not tell all the details; hence nailing down the problem is difficult. Did you mark the class DatabaseDataSource with either component or service annotation? If the DatabaseDataSource placed under different package, did you add it to the component package scan?

Comment: suppose `private GetAllNotesPresenter getAllNotesPresenter;` is missing a `@Autowired` annotation.

Comment: I marked it with component annotation. I have also service implementation class that had service annotation. Database class is in different package.

Comment: Why I should should add @Auyowired to Presenter class?

Comment: @Zookey why would you reject a code formatting edit and then have broken code formatting?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating `NotesDataSource` using a `new` and not via Spring.

`dataSource = new DatabaseDataSource();`

If you want Spring to provide dependencies for your object make it a bean and get it created via Spring. Then only Spring will know that bean needs a dependency. Spring creates an object graph, which you are breaking when you used `new`. If you create an object using `new`, it is your responsibility to provide all it's dependencies and not Spring's.

```
@Component
public class AwesomeNotesService implements NotesService {
  ...
}

@Component
public class DatabaseDataSource implements NotesDataSource {
  private final NotesService service;

  @AutoWired
  public GetAllNotesPresenterImpl(NotesService service){
      this.service = service;
  }
}

@Component
public class GetAllNotesPresenterImpl implements GetAllNotesPresenter {
    private final NotesDataSource dataSource;

    @AutoWired
    public GetAllNotesPresenterImpl(NotesDataSource dataSource){
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }
}
```

If you have multiple implementations you can use [@Qualifier](https://spring.io/blog/2014/11/04/a-quality-qualifier).

Comment: Can you please add some implementation code to your answer and I will try it and accept it